# Change keys in multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have multidimensional arrays like :

```
array:2 [▼
  "North" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Paris"
    1 => "Lille"
    2 => "Rouen"
  ]
  "South" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Montpellier"
    1 => "Marseille"
    2 => "Nice"
  ]
]
```

I want to change the keys by the key of the first level, it is possible ?

Example of output :

```
array:6 [▼
  "North" => "Paris"
  "North" => "Lille"
  "North" => "Rouen"
  "South" => "Montpellier"
  "South" => "Marseille"
  "South" => "Nice"
]
```

Is there a way to do this ?

Thank you !

Comment: You cannot have more than 1 value with the same key in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot have multiple of the same key in an associative array PHP.